# Can someone explain the solutions of the game theory problem listed below

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

Problem Statement:
Andrew, Fedor and Alex are inventive guys. Now they invent the game with strings for two players.

Given a group of n non-empty strings. During the game two players build the word together, initially the word is empty. The players move in turns. On his step player must add a single letter in the end of the word, the resulting word must be prefix of at least one string from the group. A player loses if he cannot move.

Andrew and Alex decided to play this game k times. The player who is the loser of the i-th game makes the first move in the (i + 1)-th game. Guys decided that the winner of all games is the player who wins the last (k-th) game. Andrew and Alex already started the game. Fedor wants to know who wins the game if both players will play optimally. Help him.

Input
The first line contains two integers, n and k (1 ≤ n ≤ 105; 1 ≤ k ≤ 109).

Each of the next n lines contains a single non-empty string from the given group. The total length of all strings from the group doesn't exceed 105. Each string of the group consists only of lowercase English letters.

Output
If the player who moves first wins, print "First", otherwise print "Second" (without the quotes).

Examples:

```
1 2
ab
```

Output:`Second`

especially I could not understand below Output:

```
4 2
aaaa
bbbb
ccccc
dumbavumba
```

Jury's answer : `First`

Answer (score 0):

We have 4 strings: "aaaa", "bbbb", "ccccc" and "dumbavumba", the winner of all games is the winner of the second game (k=2) and the output is **First**.

If I start the game **first**, I have only one wining solution, and it is to start with letter 'c' because the string "ccccc" is the only string with length equal to odd number. On the 5th move I will **win** the first game.

The **second** player will have to start the second (last) game with some of the remaining strings. All of the remaining strings are composed of even number of letters, which means that I  will win the second game and will be the winner of all games.